# Displaying numbers in 7 Seg Decoder using Verilog

Tags: verilog

This code should display number 0 -15. I am trying to make this code to work, but I tried everything and nothing works...

```
reg number;
number[3] = Qd;
number[2] = Qc;
number[1] = Qb;
number[0] = Qa;

wire circuitB;
reg[3:0] tenth;

comparator cm (circuitB,number);

always@(circuitB)
    if(circuitB)begin
        number[3] = 0;
        number[2] = 0;
        number[1] = number[3]&number[2]&number[1];
        number[0] = ~(number[1]^number[0]);
        tenth[0] = 1;           
    end

Dec7SegDisp big (HEX0,number);
Dec7SegDisp big1 (HEX1,tenth);
```

Qa,Qb,Qc,Qd are output from a counter.

So, things I tried :

1. using number and tenth as wire - I will get errors such as left hand assignment must have a variable data type etc.
2. using numer and tenth as reg - I get errors saying that assigng Qa,Qb,Qc and Qd to them are illegal, as Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at partII.v(22) near text "=";  expecting ".", or an identifier

And I don't know what else I can do. Thanks for reading.

Comment: assign or not, doesn't work ... I am flipping back and forth from assign and reg, neither of them works

Comment: You can't write variable 'number' by continuous and procedural assignments at the same time.

Comment: How do you suggest me to go about assigning the value then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few things you need to fix:

- you define number as a single scalar variable, but use it as an array. It should be either reg [3:0] number or wire [3:0] number.
- You should either use continuous assignments to number: **assign** number[3] = Qd; or only assign to it in an always block. The way you have it now at the beginning of the code is wrong. Why not putting all assignments to number in one single always block?
- You can't assign to number twice. Currently, you are assigning to it both at the beginning and also in the always block.
- You don't show all of your code and the description of the comparator and QA,..,QD. Perhaps you can post a more complete code here: http://www.edaplayground.com/